# How do I update a table in MySQL using an array of values and a prepared statement in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, express, prepared-statement

I have a table called "rankings" in my database that I would like to update when information is submitted. The data that is being sent to the server is in the form of a two dimensional array structured like:

```
[ [1, 78],
 [2, 77],
 [3, 76]]
```

The number on the left an ID and the number on the right is a position/score. Both of these values have already been defined in my table as 'ID' and 'score' and what I'd like to do is overwrite the originals with the new numbers. I am trying to do this using prepared statements but I get an error when performing this query.

```
  db.query('UPDATE rankings SET ID=?, score=?', [scoreTable], function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
```

The error is this:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(2, 78), (4, 77), (3, 76), (5, 75), (6, 74), (7, 73), (8, 72), (9, 71), (10, 70)' at line 1
```

The values at the end of the error are from the array I'm trying to use.

Comment: `UPDATE rankings SET ID=?, score=?` your basically saying, update EVERY record with the same ID & same score.. :   You need a WHERE..   IOW: what record are we updating?.. is it ID?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important things when working with databases: if you want to `UPDATE` or `DELETE` from a table, you should make sure you have a `WHERE` clause. Otherwise you `UPDATE` everything.

[image]

Comment: you're so edgy bro

Comment: I've updated my array so the first value can be the score and the second the ID/query now is  ` 'UPDATE rankings SET score=? WHERE ID=?' ` corresponding to score/ID however it still doesn't work, do you have any other advice/insulting meme combinations to share?

Comment: Wasn't meant to be an insult, my apologies. Sorry, are you trying to add new data to this table?

Comment: Oh I'm new to programming and acutely aware of how bad I am at it which is why it felt that way I guess. Anyway what I'd like to do is just set/update the current values of the table to the new ones from the array for each value in the table (the table and the array will always have the same length)

Comment: Cool, so I want to put it out there that it's generally not best practice to overwrite data in a database rather than adding new data. Obviously this is dependent on the case, but it's often not the best means of record keeping.

Anyways, if those records exist already, you can `UPDATE`them sort of like you are, except you must do it one row at a time. So you'll need a loop where you update one record per iteration. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. However now that I know that what I'd be doing is not a best practice I'll have to figure out some other way of going about what I'd like to do. Thank you for the information!